# How to run .m function from Matlab GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I have a GUI that collects user data in the form of numbers. I want the user to hit the pushbutton in the GUI in order to run a function file(.m file) that uses the imputed data of the user to display results

My function file is **dish.m**

The GUI pushbutton function is this:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)

% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

What code do i need to run?

Comment: So this is what i entered but i had errrors

Comment: dish ();
[Er,h,Freq] = dish(Er,h,Freq); % Passing Er,h,Freq values to dish.m

Comment: **Error message is this** Error using dish (line 21)
Not enough input arguments.

Comment: Please, post the function definition and the line 21 of the code, so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Why the first `dish();` call? Intuition tells me zero arguments is "not enough input arguments"...